# Moving my Xaxis to the bottom of my stacked chart in Plotly

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly

I have a chart I'm working with in plotly and I can't for the life of me figure out how to move the X axis of my graph to the bottom of the figure.

[image]

Here is the code I have so far:
df = pd.read_csv(filename)

```
trace1= go.Scatter(x=df['Timestamp'],
                         y=df['CLE'],
                         name='Crude',
                        mode='lines+markers')


trace2 = go.Scatter(x=df['Timestamp'],
                         y=df['y_pred'],
                         name='Model',
                         mode='lines+markers')

trace3 = go.Bar(x=df['Timestamp'],
                y=df['ModelDiff'],
                name='Diff',
                yaxis='y2'
                )

data = [trace1, trace2, trace3]
layout = go.Layout(title='Crude vs Model',
                   yaxis=dict(
                       domain=[.25, 1]),
                   legend=dict(
                       orientation='h',

                   ),
                   yaxis2=dict(
                       domain=[0, .25])
                   )



return go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
```

Comment: it seems it has something to do with using two `yaxis`, how does your plot look using just one `yaxis`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `xaxis=dict(anchor="y2")` inside your `go.Layout()` call to attach the x-axis to the lower y-axis.

Comment: i ended up moving the first two traces to the 2nd yaxis and that worked as well. will try this.